# Adiabatic evolution for initial Hamiltonian on Hadamard basis and problem Hamiltonian as diagonal

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-computer, adiabatic

This is spawned from a comment at the answer to [one of my previous questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/82487/confusion-about-a-lemma-on-the-time-constraint-of-an-adiabatic-evolution-arxiv).

Someone suggested to me that claiming the following statement might be NP-hard. Could anyone please help me to figure out whether it is true?

> If the eigenstate of the initial Hamiltonian are superposition of all
>   possible states we cannot perform the adiabatic evolution with a
>   diagonal Hamiltonian as the problem Hamiltonian.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Statements aren't **NP**-hard. *Problems* (a family of related yes-or-no questions) can be, however. If you only mean to ask whether or not your statement is true, you should remove the reference to **NP**-hardness.